# Wireframing tool to design a website idea

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation, tools, interface-design

I have nothing to do with design, because I don't know how to mix two colors. Some time ago, I've read about some tools which are used in the creation of interfaces for application and web pages.

In that article were mentioned some tools, and one of them was a free firefox add-on. I'm not looking specifically for that add-on, but the idea is that those types of applications aren't very advanced in order to be used by professionals in the design field.

Do you have any idea about what I'm talking about? Can you name some of those applications?

Comment: are you asking about 'wireframing' tools?

Comment: @DA01: It sure sounds like it.

Answer (score 4):

I use two Wireframing tools

- Balsamiq mockups - Simple wireframing tool, fast to use, cheap, awesome. http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups
- AxureRP - Complex, very complete, almost a working web app, expensive, awesome. http://www.axure.com

Have fun :)

Comment: "almost a working web app" uh, no. It 'looks' like a working app but, alas, the code Axure creates is horrendous. Axure has its places but it's important to realize it's nothing like the actual working app under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

For most wireframing I use a pencil, paper and markers. I find it's the quickest method for me. For more detailed stuff I may jump into a vector illustration app (AI or Inkscape or the like) or use some of the drawing apps on the iPad for that.

Comment: Sometimes pencil and paper really works best.

Comment: They really do (and whiteboard rocks)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mateus' answer, any basic vector drawing tools will do the job. Presentation software such as MS PowerPoint, OpenOffice Impress, Apple Keynote work well, as you can show changes over multiple pages or using basic animation. You probably have one of these available to you right now...

More complex vector drawing tools such as MS Visio, Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator can also be used.

Although UI element libraries won't be included out-of-the-box for any of these, you'll be able to find some for download.

Answer (score 1):

This one http://softwareprototyping.net/review-justproto/ JustProto is a good thing to try between Axure and BAlsamiq :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WireframeSketcher wireframing tool](http://wireframesketcher.com). Here's what it can do for you:

[image: Website wireframe]

Comment: It's a matter of preference. Many users feel that wobbly lines communicate better that a screen is just an idea sketch and not a final design. You can switch to straght lines if you wish.